# Summing values of identical keys in a deeply nested hash

Tags: ruby

I may have posted this nested hash before. This hash consist of 4 levels for each parent key (:home, :away). I want to access the 4th level for each parent key in order to add all of the :points values together, then I would want to compare each of the summed values and figure out which one is the largest value. I have attempted this by myself however I get an error of

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (repl):136:in `[]'
>   (repl):136:in`block in winning_team' (repl):135:in `each'
>   (repl):135:in`winning_team' (repl):158:in `'

The hash and my attempt at this code are below, any explanation of why I get this error and any improvements to get the desired output would be really helpful. My apologies if its too messy understand.

```
game_hash = {
    :home => 
    {
        :team_name => "Brooklyn Nets",
        :colors => ["Black", "White"],
        :players => {
            :player1 => {
                :name => "Alan Anderson",
                :number => 0,
                :shoe_size => 16,
                :points => 22,
                :rebounds => 12,
                :assists => 12,
                :steals => 3,
                :blocks => 1,
                :slam_dunks => 1
            },
            :player2 => {
                :name => "Reggie Evans",
                :number => 30,
                :shoe_size => 14,
                :points => 12,
                :rebounds => 12,
                :assists => 12,
                :steals => 12,
                :blocks => 12,
                :slam_dunks => 7
            },
            :player3 => {
                :name => "Brook Lopez",
                :number => 11,
                :shoe_size => 17,
                :points => 17,
                :rebounds => 19,
                :assists => 10,
                :steals => 3,
                :blocks => 1,
                :slam_dunks => 15
            },
            :player4 => {
                :name => "Mason Plumlee",
                :number => 1,
                :shoe_size => 19,
                :points => 26,
                :rebounds => 12,
                :assists => 6,
                :steals => 3,
                :blocks => 8,
                :slam_dunks => 5
            },
            :player5 => {
                :name => "Jason Terry",
                :number => 31,
                :shoe_size => 15,
                :points => 19,
                :rebounds => 2,
                :assists => 2,
                :steals => 4,
                :blocks => 11,
                :slam_dunks => 1

            }
    },      

    :away =>
    {
        :team_name => "Charlotte Hornets",
        :colors => ["Turquoise", "Purple"],
        :players => {
            :player1 => {
                :name => "Jeff Adrien",
                :number => 4,
                :shoe_size => 18,
                :points => 10,
                :rebounds => 1,
                :assists => 1,
                :steals => 2,
                :blocks => 7,
                :slam_dunks => 2
            },
            :player2 => {
                :name => "Bismak Biyombo",
                :number => 0,
                :shoe_size => 16,
                :points => 12,
                :rebounds => 4,
                :assists => 7,
                :steals => 7,
                :blocks => 15,
                :slam_dunks => 10
            },
            :player3 => {
                :name => "DeSagna Diop",
                :number => 2,
                :shoe_size => 14,
                :points => 24,
                :rebounds => 12,
                :assists => 12,
                :steals => 4,
                :blocks => 5,
                :slam_dunks => 5
            },
            :player4 => {
                :name => "Ben Gordon",
                :number => 8,
                :shoe_size => 15,
                :points => 33,
                :rebounds => 3,
                :assists => 2,
                :steals => 1,
                :blocks => 1,
                :slam_dunks => 0
            },
            :player5 => {
                :name => "Brendon Haywood",
                :number => 33,
                :shoe_size => 15,
                :points => 6,
                :rebounds => 12,
                :assists => 12,
                :steals => 22,
                :blocks => 5,
                :slam_dunks => 12
            }
        }
    }
}
}


    ##winning team
def winning_team(game_data)
  #finding the sum of all :points in :home

  game_data[:home].each do |attribute, value|
    value[:players].each do |player, player_data|
      score_1 = player_data.find{|k| k[:points]}.sum
    end 
  end 

  #finding the sum of all :points in :away
  game_data[:away].each do |attribute, value|
    value[:players].each do |player, player_data|
      score_2 = player_data.find{|k| k[:points]}.sum
    end 
  end 

  #outputting a final statement of who won the game


    if score_1 < score_2 
    puts "Brooklyn Nets won the game"
  else 
    puts "Charlotte Hornets won the game"
  end




end
```

Comment: _Shameless plug:_ I maintain a package [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor) that is explicitly designed to iterate / map / reduce deeply nested Enumerables. You might want to give it a try.

Comment: Authors of questions are encouraged to pare their examples down to their essentials. Here, for example, each player has nine attributes, but only one (`:number`) is relevant to the question. If you included just, say, two attributes, perhaps `;name` and `:number`, the example would be no less relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
game_hash[:home][:players].sum { |_, h| h[:points] }
#⇒  96
```

The same for `:away`.

Comment: I get an error of undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
(repl):132:in `<main>' when i do  it for :away

Comment: I bet you might fix the issue yourself. I showed the approach.

Comment: I'm not sure why its throwing an error, it should work from my understanding

Comment: You have a malformed hash. `:away` should probably be on the same level as `:home`. Yours has `:away` one layer down. `game_hash[:home][:away][:players].sum { |_, h| h[:points] } #⇒ 85`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the winning team you could use [`Enumerable#max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) along with [`Enumerable#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum).

```rb
winning_team = game_hash.values.max_by do |team|
  team[:players].sum { |_, h| h[:points] }
end

puts winning_team[:team_name]
```

Alternatively, you can use something like [`Hashie::Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) or [`OpenStruct`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.2/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) to turn the Hashes into more friendly objects and use accessor methods like this:

```rb
require 'hashie/mash'
game = Hashie::Mash.new(game_hash)

winning_team = [game.home, game.away].max_by do |team|
  team.players.values.sum(&:points)
end

puts winning_team.team_name
```